# Transferring points acquired by unlocking achievements to Bioware Points?

Tags: achievements, dragon-age-origins

I have unlocked few achievements during my playthrough of Dragon Age:Origins. Now, unlocking these achievements gives you Bioware Points, however my account's Bioware Points count shows as zero.
How can I transfer them to Bioware points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different point types. They more for "show", they do not have value, the points that you see there can not be used to buy stuff sadly.

To get points listed on your Bioware account you have to buy them, I tried finding a link but they moved there site around. If you look on the community site you can log in and then buy points.